# cannot access self in objective-c codeblock

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to call a function from a callback code block in objective-c, with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WHVUser *user = [WHVUser sharedManager];
    WHVHTTPClient *http = [[WHVHTTPClient alloc] init];

    self.buttonInitRegistration.hidden = false; //this works!

    [http doRequestWithData:@{ @"access_token": user.token } atUrl:@"/me" andCallback:^(NSDictionary *data){
        NSLog(@"this block of code is certainly executed");
        self.buttonInitRegistration.hidden = false; //this doesn't!
    }];
}
```

Now, the problem is that basically when I do `self.buttonInitRegistration.hidden = false` inside the callback nothing happens but, if I do it outside, it does! I am pretty sure it has something to do with scoping, but I am not confident on how to fix this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the NSLog(@"this block... firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do UI updates on the main thread, so assuming your callback is executed, try this;

```
  [http doRequestWithData:@{ @"access_token": user.token } atUrl:@"/me" andCallback:^(NSDictionary *data){
    NSLog(@"this block of code is certainly executed");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.buttonInitRegistration.hidden = false; //this doesn't!
    });
}];
```

Comment: +1, but actually we can't be sure, if `WHVHTTPClient` does not call the whole block on the main thread.

Comment: Alright, I see! This means I need to use that piece of code every single time I have an async request that then modifies UI, like change viewControllers, visibility, etc.?

Comment: @vikingosegundo That's a point as well, it would be more DRY to be able to do that in my WHVHTTPClient, right?

Comment: @user3060636, if you are the creator of `WHVHTTPClient `, you can call the call back block on the main thread anyway.

Comment: @user3060636, I would do so if there is a big change that most calls will affect the UI.

Comment: @vikingosegundo good point, although one would assume that to avoid blocking, it would return on the background. Imagine if the user executed a long process on the returned data, this could potentially block the UI at an inappropriate time.

Comment: @MDB983, usually the network call is the one long task. and that is done at that point. If the user does something long-running there, he can still dispatch it again.